# Scala: how can I perform actions when test are over?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I'm using `scalatest_2.11` version 2.2.1. I'm trying to write test that run on a SparkContext. How can I initiate a SparkContext when the tests begin, take this Sc thorugh all the tests and then stop it when they are all done?

(I know that it suppose to stop by itself, but I'sd still like to do it myself)

Comment: check out https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base - does that and much more, specifically take a look at https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/src/main/1.3/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/SharedSparkContext.scala

Comment: Here's a simple `beforeAll` example: https://github.com/kevinmeredith/scalatest_beforeAll_testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BeforeAndAfterAll](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.html) from ScalaTest. Define a base trait that starts and stops the SparkContext and use it with your other tests.

```
trait SparkTest extends BeforeAndAfterAll {
  self: Suite =>

  @transient var sc: SparkContext = _

  override def beforeAll {
    val conf = new SparkConf().
      setMaster("local[*]").
      setAppName("test")
    sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    super.beforeAll()
  }

  override def afterAll: Unit = {
    try {
      sc.stop()
    } finally {
      super.afterAll
    }
  }

}

// Mix-in the trait with your tests like below.
class MyTest extends FunSuite with SparkTest {
  test("my test") {
    // you can access "sc" here.
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) I'm getting `SparkTest does not conform to BeforeAndAfterAll with Suite`, (2) How do I transfer the SparkContext to the `afterAll`? Am I allowed to change function arity?

Comment: could you please elaborate on the `@transient` addition? Why is that necessary? And on the `self: Suite` part, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @transient helps in avoiding serialization issues. Spark serializes the class (if something is referred from it inside a transformation). In that case, you will get serialization error because SparkContext is not serializable. Adding transient gives a hint so that it is not serialized. You can ignore it if it is not required in your case. Self type acts as an alias to "this" and it allows to access other instance members through "this". A simple and nice explanation here. http://www.slideshare.net/LappleApple/scala-self-types-by-gregor-hein

Comment: And BeforeAndAfterAll uses self type and when we are extending that, we have to comply to that. That's why it is required here.